# Path or naming shema for files with classes that marked by @SuiteClasses (JUnit4)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, naming-conventions, junit4

Today I trapped into problem with `@SuiteClasses`.

I recently joined to new project with relatively young/unexperienced team and found drawbacks in project testing architecture:

- Test files with classes which marked as @SuiteClasses placed in same packages as regular tests.

  `includes` tags for `surefire` plug-in look like `<include>com/company/project/core/**/*Test.java</include>` in our `pom.xml` and we have naming schema for suites like: `<PREFIX>SuiteTest.java` so **mvn test** command executes same test twice or more times...
- Recently I integrate `DbUnit` to project. Running DbUnit test from IDE or test-suite which refer for DbUnit tests from IDE are ok. But from command line it stuck on DbUnit test forever if any test-suite refer to any DbUnit tests. This cause CI `Jenkins` to stop building and delivering project to test team...

Root of problems lies in naming schema for test suites.

Is that right to put suites into same package as regular  tests or use separate package like:

```
com.company.project.testsuites
```

Or may be use different naming schema for test-suites to distinct them from regular tests (instead of `<PREFIX>SuiteTest.java` use `<PREFIX>TestSuite.java`)? Which names do you suggest from your practice?